# Show id even result is empty?

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have the SQL command:

```
SELECT 
vinculo.id,
data start, 
count(*) title 
from 
atendimento_regulacao 
join vinculo on vinculo.id = atendimento_regulacao.vinculo_id 
where data = '2019-07-02' 
group by vinculo.usuario_id, atendimento_regulacao.data
```

The result is empty because not exists none record on `where data = '2019-07-02'`

How to show the `id` like below?

```
id | start | title
 1 |       |
```

Comment: You are aggregating by `vinculo .usuario_id` but fetching `vinculo.id`.  The query doesn't make sense and should cause an error.

Comment: a possible solution can be using UNION and ROW_NUMBER() filter and show the empty record based on if you have results or not..  But without example data and expected results it is hard to make (solid) queries ... See [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `CROSS JOIN` to generate the rows and `LEFT JOIN` to bring in the results:

```
select v.id, d.dte as start, count(ar.vinculo_id) as num_title 
from (select '2019-07-02' as dte) d cross join
     vinculo v left join
     atendimento_regulacao ar
     on v.id = ar.vinculo_id and ar.data = d.dte 
group by v.id, d.dte;
```

If you really want to aggregate by `v.usuario_id`, then include it in both the `select` and `group by`.

Notes:

- The structure of the query easily extends to multiple dates.
- The `GROUP BY` uses the same columns in the `SELECT`.
- Table aliases make the query easier to write and to read.
- Qualify *all* column references in a query that has more than one table reference.
- The `COUNT()` uses a column from `ar` so it can return `0`.

For the specific case of a single date, you can use conditional aggregation:

```
select v.id, '2019-07-02' as start,
       count(ar.vinculo_id) as num_title 
from vinculo v left join
     atendimento_regulacao ar
     on v.id = ar.vinculo_id and ar.data = '2019-07-02'
group by v.id;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `RIGHT JOIN`, and convert your `count` to the one below, otherwise it shows zero whenever didn't find to count anything.

```
SELECT v.id, a.data start, 
       case when count(*) is null then null end title 
  FROM atendimento_regulacao a
 RIGHT JOIN vinculo v 
    ON v.id = a.vinculo_id 
   AND a.data = '2019-07-02'  
 GROUP BY v.usuario_id, a.data;
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=a8da3a283e42ec71a7b9fbffc43c1e0d)</kbd>

Comment: This show others dates than '2019-07-02' and not show the id

Comment: @ItaloRodrigo Yes, I should say `RIGHT JOIN` instead.